# push a PHP variable's value into an array created by mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php

My code fetches several fields from a row in MySQL, makes a MYSQL_ASSOC array via mysql_fetch_array(), and formats it to JSON to return to Javascript in the browser. This part works. I want to additionally insert a PHP generated variable and its value to describe the time. A field exists for this variable and the timestamp code works in another script to insert the time of the original first post. In this script, I want the value to be the time a second PHP update script runs, not the original time value in the database. Despite a lot of trying, I can't get this last part to work. Here's relevant code:

```
$timeStamp = date("Ymd");
$userIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$postingID = "$timeStamp-$userIP-u";
$latestUpdateID = str_replace(".", "", "$postingID")

//some pre-processing to make $fields_sql, an array to use in the SELECT

$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT $fields_sql FROM residence WHERE propertyID = '$propertyID'");
if( mysql_num_rows( $fetch ) ){
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ){
        for( $i = 0; $i < count( $propertyFields ); $i++ ) {
            $row_array[ $propertyFields[$i] ] = mysql_real_escape_string( $row[ $propertyFields[$i] ] );
        }
        array_push( $return_arr,$row_array ); 
        //get [{"city":"Rochester","streetAddress":"100 Main", etc.}]
    }
    $propertyFields[ 'latestUpdateID' ] = $latestUpdateID; //get "latestUpdateID":""
    array_push( $return_arr,$propertyFields[ 'latestUpdateID' ] ); //pushed in but no value
//want [{"city":"Rochester","streetAddress":"100 Main", "latestUpdateID":"20131107", etc.}]
} else { die('<li class=error>Ooops</li> }

echo json_encode( $return_arr );
```

Two comments: 1. As you can see the query returns only 1 row. The while loop is probably not needed, but I don't know how to do it any other way. Suggestions, that also fix the problem, would be doubly appreciated. 2. Yes, I know the mysql_ family of commands is deprecated. I have several of these and my next project is to convert them all to PDO, but at the moment, I understand PDO a lot less than this stuff.

Comment: What's your intent with that call to `mysql_real_escape_string()` in the for loop?  That definitely isn't necessary, and potentially harmful to your data form if you're sending this down as JSON.  `json_encode()` will handle the all the correct encoding.

Comment: Does `$propertyFields` have numeric or string keys? I see you treat it both ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$row` contains all the information you need and escaping using `mysql_real_escape_string()` is only needed when you output to a mysql database, so just do a:

```
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC )) {
    $row['latestUpdateID'] = $latestUpdateID;
    echo json_encode( $row );
}
```

**Edit:** If more than just that row is supposed to be returned:

```
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC )) {
    $row['latestUpdateID'] = $latestUpdateID;
    $return_arr[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode( $return_arr );
```

Comment: And don't forget to append `$row` onto `$return_arr`, which is the array holding multiple rows.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski You're probably right, it's a little unclear if more is returned in the `echo`, will edit...

Comment: Thanks, jeroen, your edited version with Michael Berkowski's input works like a charm. Thanks to Michael B, also. Its very simple code, so I think I can transform it to PDO as a next step. I'm interested in further thoughts about mysql_real_escape_string(). I have read that one should use it both inbound to the database, and outbound from a database, in case the database has been hacked with malicious code that would then get sent to the user's browser. What are your thoughts about the hacked and outbound-from-database scenario?

Comment: @Mike_Laird No, you should always escape / encode for the medium you are outputting to, so if you output to html (the browser), you use `htmlspecialchars()`, no sql functions.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you need to put $latestUpdateId into return_arr, check this code:

```
$fetch = mysql_query('SELECT '.$fields_sql.' FROM `residence` WHERE `propertyID`='.intval(propertyID, 10).' limit 1'); // note intval and limit 1
if( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ) {
    $row['latestUpdateID'] = $latestUpdateID;
    echo json_encode( $row );
}
else { die('<li class=error>Ooops</li>'); }
```

note: you do not need to use mysql_escape or mysql_real_escape functions, as you are not WRITE into database, you're READING from it

ps: single quotes are usually faster then double quotes in strings, intval is needed to prevent SQL injection and limit 1 usually faster if propertyID is not PK

Comment: I tried your restatement of $fetch, and the PHP script did not work. In looking at it, I suspect problems with single and double quotes. I will tinker with it. Thanks for the security thought.

Comment: Ilya, the PHP syntax that works for me is $fetch = mysql_query("SELECT $fields_sql FROM residence WHERE propertyID = '".(int)$propertyID."' LIMIT 1"); I understand the security role of int() limits the variable to an integer. I understand LIMIT allows only 1 response. But I don't get the security role of LIMIT in this case. What is it protecting against here in an attempted SQL injection?

Comment: @Mike_Laird `limit 1 usually faster if propertyID is not PK` it is not about security